# What did God the Supreme Being create actually: Body or Mind?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, dharma, moksha, human

In Bhagavad Gita, we encounter these words by Lord Krishna:

> 'I am the Creator and Sustainer of all living beings'.(Bhagavad Gita 9.5)

All 'living beings' are endowed with consciousness that all lifeless things are devoid of. And all human beings are endowed with something called mind. The creator of all 'living beings' must be the creator of their bodies, consciousness, and mind. Hence, Lord Krishna must also be responsible for all acts, be they good or bad, performed by any humans as well as animals. Thus, none deserve to be looked on as sinner, and so none need to attain moksha in order to get rid of the infinite cycle of birth, death & rebirth.

Nevertheless, we hear Lord Krishna say, 'People who have no faith in this dharma are unable to attain me. They repeatedly come back to this world in the cycle of birth and death.'

'People who have no faith in this dharma' are devoid of it because Lord Krishna has Not created their mind full of 'faith in his dharma', Right?

If Not so, every sensible mind is moved to wonder whether Lord Krishna created the body alone, not consciousness nor mind nor the faculty of reason. But then, the Supreme Being cannot claim to be the creator of any 'living beings'.

Comment: *‘I think, Italics and Bold, and Headers can be used on emphasizing any text.’* -https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/how-can-we-differentiate-scriptural-quotes-and-question-quotes-while-answering-q?r=SearchResults. This is normal protocol which even space age people may follow.

Comment: So, your claim is 'Maya' is Not meant to mislead the benighted people because Lord Krishna has granted them 'free will'. Well, but if a benighted fool exercises his 'free will' given to him by None other than the Supreme Being HimSelf and does something wrong, why should he deserve to be held responsible for this? IsN't it Lord Krishna's fault that He created 'Maya' and gave him 'free will' but deprived him of the Enlightenment he needed to be able to know the Right from the wrong and the bad from the Good?

Comment: Is it Not true that Lord Krishna, the Creator of everything, created 'Maya', mind, 'free will', and all 'desires' in your benighted mind too? So, why should you deserve to be punished by being made to undergo the 'cycle of endless births'?

Comment: Why do you think Lord Krishna created the  'cycle of endless births [& deaths]'? Or, do you claim that Lord Krishna created everything except your 'desires' and the  'cycle of endless births [& deaths]' ?

Comment: @PrakashRP Present birth of Mr. X is a result of his past birth(s). Past birth(s) of Mr. X are due to his "still further into the past" births and so on. For a phenomenon which is beginningless, like birth-death cycle, there is no original reason for creation, because there was never a first creation. The cycle itself was never originally created. Only each instance in the cycle is created.

Comment: @zero Whether there was an actual “first time” is itself a question,so I don’t think it’s safe to assume it as such (granted a number of swamis have replied in the negative to the question,nevertheless questions do still arise)